# Force post ID to be slug

Tags: wordpress, slug

I'm using **a heavily custom theme that uses needs custom permalinks** to be in this format:

```
    /%category/%postname%/
```

but, i want my permalinks to be in this

```
    /%category/%post_id%/
```

Is there a way to force the %post_id% to be set as slug without changing anything in the Permalinks Settings?

** To explain this a bit more, my client wants to keep the title of a post in the admin, but he wants it visible only in the admin. So what i need is to keep the titles of the post and force the post_id to be the slug

Answer (score 0):

Go to Dashboard->Settings->Permalink

In custom structure use `/%post_id%/`

and save it

Comment: if i use anything other than /%category/%postname%/ some of the theme's functions wont work